# Merge dictionaries with the same values to a single dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries so:

```
[{'point': '-2.43896484341047, 53.4369463378926',
  'time': '2015-06-17 12:51:16+01:00',
  'title': 'Queen and Royal Family Members Visit Manchester'},
 {'point': '-0.150032043436181, 51.5402430395087',
  'time': '2015-06-20 12:52:29+01:00',
  'title': 'Price Harry Quits the Army to Concentrate on Charity Work'},
 {'point': '-0.150032043436181, 51.5402430395087',
  'time': '2015-06-26 17:01:19+01:00',
  'title': 'A true friend: Ukraine president asks Tony Blair to take on advisory role'},
 {'point': '-77.1075439345789, 35.456615048032',
  'time': '2015-06-26 17:01:19+01:00',
  'title': 'A true friend: Ukraine president asks Tony Blair to take on advisory role'}]
```

I'd like to be able to search through the dictionaries and in instances where two dictionaries share the same title and time, merge the title and time and retain the different point values, creating something like this:

```
[{'point': '-2.43896484341047, 53.4369463378926',
  'time': '2015-06-17 12:51:16+01:00',
  'title': 'Queen and Royal Family Members Visit Manchester'},
 {'point': '-0.150032043436181, 51.5402430395087',
  'time': '2015-06-20 12:52:29+01:00',
  'title': 'Price Harry Quits the Army to Concentrate on Charity Work'},
 {'point': ['-0.150032043436181, 51.5402430395087', '-77.1075439345789, 35.456615048032'],
  'time': '2015-06-26 17:01:19+01:00',
  'title': 'A true friend: Ukraine president asks Tony Blair to take on advisory role'}]
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow!  Where, exactly, is your problem?  Did you try something and get an erroneous result?  Is there a specific step of the process you described that you don't know how to do?  In short:  **what have you tried?**

Comment: @blz Thanks for the quick response. I've been trying to return all dicts within the list with the same title and time values to start with which i'm struggling with. My thinking after that was to get all points and create a list within a new dictionary.

Comment: Have you considered defining your own class instead of using a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this shorter solution:

```
dicts = [
 {'point': '-2.43896484341047, 53.4369463378926',
  'time': '2015-06-17 12:51:16+01:00',
  'title': 'Queen and Royal Family Members Visit Manchester'},
 {'point': '-0.150032043436181, 51.5402430395087',
  'time': '2015-06-20 12:52:29+01:00',
  'title': 'Price Harry Quits the Army to Concentrate on Charity Work'},
 {'point': '-0.150032043436181, 51.5402430395087',
  'time': '2015-06-26 17:01:19+01:00',
  'title': 'A true friend: Ukraine president asks Tony Blair to take on advisory role'},
 {'point': '-77.1075439345789, 35.456615048032',
  'time': '2015-06-26 17:01:19+01:00',
  'title': 'A true friend: Ukraine president asks Tony Blair to take on advisory role'}]

ans = []
for time, title in set((d['time'], d['title']) for d in dicts):
    points = [d['point'] for d in dicts if (d['time'], d['title']) == (time, title)]
    ans.append({
        'point' : points if len(points) > 1 else points[0],
        'time'  : time,
        'title' : title })
```

The result is stored in the `ans` variable and has the expected structure - although the elements in the output list might come out in a different order, because I'm using a `set` to find out the unique "keys":

```
[{'title': 'A true friend: Ukraine president asks Tony Blair to take on advisory role',
  'time': '2015-06-26 17:01:19+01:00',
  'point': ['-0.150032043436181, 51.5402430395087', '-77.1075439345789, 35.456615048032']},
 {'title': 'Price Harry Quits the Army to Concentrate on Charity Work',
  'time': '2015-06-20 12:52:29+01:00',
  'point': '-0.150032043436181, 51.5402430395087'},
 {'title': 'Queen and Royal Family Members Visit Manchester',
  'time': '2015-06-17 12:51:16+01:00',
  'point': '-2.43896484341047, 53.4369463378926'}]
```

Comment: ah yes, that is a lot more concise and easier to read. thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Try this, sorry for my poor naming conventions :

```
your_dict = [{'point': '-2.43896484341047, 53.4369463378926',
  'time': '2015-06-17 12:51:16+01:00',
  'title': 'Queen and Royal Family Members Visit Manchester'},
 {'point': '-0.150032043436181, 51.5402430395087',
  'time': '2015-06-20 12:52:29+01:00',
  'title': 'Price Harry Quits the Army to Concentrate on Charity Work'},
 {'point': '-0.150032043436181, 51.5402430395087',
  'time': '2015-06-26 17:01:19+01:00',
  'title': 'A true friend: Ukraine president asks Tony Blair to take on advisory role'},
 {'point': '-77.1075439345789, 35.456615048032',
  'time': '2015-06-26 17:01:19+01:00',
  'title': 'A true friend: Ukraine president asks Tony Blair to take on advisory role'}]

def merge_your_dictcts(x):
    dd = {'title':x[0]['title'],'time':x[0]['time']}
    points = []
    for d in x:
        points.append(d['point'])
    dd['point'] = points
    return dd
final_list = []
for k in your_dict:
    x =  [j for j in your_dict if j['time'] == k['time'] and j['title'] == k['title']]
    if len(x) >= 2:
        if merge_your_dictcts(x) not in final_list:
            final_list.append(merge_your_dictcts(x))
    else:
        final_list.append(x[0])
print(final_list)
```

Output:

```
[{
    'title': 'Queen and Royal Family Members Visit Manchester',
    'time': '2015-06-17 12:51:16+01:00',
    'point': '-2.43896484341047, 53.4369463378926'
}, {
    'title': 'Price Harry Quits the Army to Concentrate on Charity Work',
    'time': '2015-06-20 12:52:29+01:00',
    'point': '-0.150032043436181, 51.5402430395087'
}, {
    'point': ['-0.150032043436181, 51.5402430395087', '-77.1075439345789, 35.456615048032'],
    'time': '2015-06-26 17:01:19+01:00',
    'title': 'A true friend: Ukraine president asks Tony Blair to take on advisory role'
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Make one pass to gather the duplicate articles and a second pass to emit the grouped articles as you've described:

```
# Gather duplicate articles
mergedict = {}
for article in news:
    key = article['time'], article['title']
    value = article['point']
    mergedict.setdefault(key, []).append(value)

# Format output
result = []
for (time, title), points in mergedict.items():
    points = points if len(points) > 1 else points[0]
    article = {'time': time, 'title': title, 'points': points}
    result.append(article)
```